# Exporting database - unknown or incorrect time zone

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm trying to export database using phpMyAdmin 3.4.5 same way as I many times did.

But, in .sql file are html tags. So, I saved .sql as an .html and opened it. There is a message:

```
Error

SQL query: Edit Edit
SET time_zone = "+00:00"

MySQL said: Documentation
#1298 - Unknown or incorrect time zone: '+00:00'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. set export method to "custom"
2. uncheck "*Dump TIMESTAMP columns in UTC (enables TIMESTAMP columns to be dumped and reloaded between servers in different time zones)*" checkbox on the very bottom of the page

tested on XAMPP for Windows 5.6.19-0

Answer (score 2):

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-set-timezone-per-connection/

You may want to set your time zone.

```
SET time_zone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
```

or

```
SET time_zone = '00:00';
```

Not

```
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
```

Comment: i have values in mysql.time_zone_name table, but still getting same error when i execute query. if i uncheck 'Display comments' and 'Dump TIMESTAMP columns in UTC' export works.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried every solution found in the web but nothing works. Maybe I not able to apply them!!!!
But if you are experiencing the same problem and you are able to change phpMyAdmin settings you can easyly solve removing the flag in export UTC time in the export sql settings.
Sorry I couldn't be more exaustive because I'm using italian version of XAMPP and phpMyAdmin.
Please excuse my bad English.

Comment: yes, like i comment before, unchecking "Dump TIMESTAMP columns in UTC" is a solution

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem on my Mac. 
I know how to resolve this problem. I access into phpmyadmin by this link

```
http://longs-macbook-pro.local/phpmyadmin
```

(Long is my name),

NOT

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
```

I hope you can resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the timezone is missing, for Linux, BSD, and Mac OS X, you need to load the timezone table into the `mysql` database to support all cities and times:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root mysql
```

This will support all of these timezones:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones